# Migrate usage of Google Analytics classes to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

How should one migrate usage of Google Analytics classes such as `com.google.android.gms.analytics.ecommerce.Product` and `com.google.android.gms.analytics.ecommerce.ProductAction` to Firebase?

It doesn't appear that Firebase has corresponding concepts.  And the official documentation offers no guidance on this.